# What subject in mathematics investigates the type of problems that constitute the LSAT "logic games" (example given)?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, terminology

For my own curiosity, I read part of an LSAT study guide yesterday. The "logic games" section comprised questions like,

> An advertising executive must schedule the advertising during a particular television show. Seven different consecutive time slots are available for advertisements during a commercial break, and are numbered one through seven in the order that they will be aired. Seven different advertisements – B, C, D, F, H, J, and K – must be aired during the show. Only one advertisement can occupy each time slot. The assignment of the advertisements to the slots is subject to the following restrictions:
>
> - B and D must occupy consecutive time slots.
> - B must be aired during an earlier time slot than K.
> - D must be aired during a later time slot than H.
> - If H does not occupy the fourth time slot, then F must occupy the fourth time slot.
> - K and J cannot occupy consecutively numbered time slots.
>
> Which of the following could be a possible list of the 
>   advertisements in the order that they are aired?
>
> 1. BDFHJCK
> 2. CJBHDKF
> 3. HBDFJCK
> 4. LHDBFKJC
> 5. HJDBFKC

I surmised that combinatoricians investigate problems like the one above. However, I have a vague conception of combinatorics, so I don't know that they do.

So What subject in mathematics investigates the type of questions that constitute the LSAT "logic games".

Thank you

-Hal

Comment: Combinatorics might be closest fit. But really this is abusing a human to execut a backtracking algorithm. (Except with multiple choiices given - where it is just a test of textual understanding)

Comment: Skipping letters in the alphabet is just being a douche of an examiner. Just sayin'.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Agreed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Boolean Algebra".

If you are trying to become proficient in Boolean Algebra for it's own sake, then I recommend introductory Digital Design (Engineering) books to learn techniques like Karnaugh maps and general "combinatorial logic" (as it is called in Digital Design curriculum).

This particular LSAT problem is a type of problem that checks how organized you are at solving things.  Consider two approaches to solving the problem:

First : check each bullet once.  Memorize "B must be next to D" and mark off all answers that don't match.  Then memorize "B before K" and mark off all answers that don't match (skip the ones already marked off).  Continue until you only have 1 answer left.

Second : Memorize "BDFHJCK".  Check that if it matches each bullet, constantly looking back and forth because you can't actually memorize it.  Then memorize "CJBHDKF".  Then check if it matches each bullet.  Continue until you have a match.

Obviously the first method is easier and faster. *But most students will attempt the second approach* because they are used to solving problems 1 question at a time, 1 possible answer at a time.

Some standardized exams will have a set of five conditions like the above, and then 10 or 15 questions asking which answer matches the conditions (the ASVAB, a military exam, was one of them).  The first approach can answer all the questions in 40s, the second approach can take 8 to 10 minutes.  They are testing "how long does it take this kid to realize he's doing it the slow way" rather than your grasp of predicate algebra.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd call this mathematics at all. It seems to be just a matter of reading the restrictions and comparing them, one by one, to the proposed schedules.  (That's essentially DanielV's "First" approach, except that, in general, you shouldn't "Continue until you only have 1 answer left" unless the problem guarantees that there's exactly one schedule that works. In general, when there's no such guarantee, you should continue until you've gone through all the restrictions.)